# jquery and php ajax sessions

Tags: php, jquery, session

**Here is what I do:**

my login form is on www.mysite.com/login.html: (subdomain www!)

```
 function authenticate(userName, password) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: 'http://server.mysite.com/ajax/auth.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: 'vardas='+userName+'&psw='+password,
        success: function (data) {
                {
                    window.location.replace('/main.html');
                }
        }
    })
    }
```

Here is my ajax/auth.php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mysite.com");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

session_start();
$_SESSION["ok"] = 1111; <- test value
```

Here is main.php:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#home').load('http://server.mysite.com/ajax/loader.php', function() {
    })
  });
</script>
<div id=home></div>
```

Here is my ajax/loader.php :)

```
<?
    header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mysite.com");
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

    session_start();

    var_dump ($_SESSION); <---- OUTPUT IS (0) EMPTY!! Why ?
?>
```

**Why this does'nt work? I always get $_SESSION empty.**

Comment: Is this cross-domain, or within the same domain?

Answer (score 2):

`session_start();` *MUST* be the very first thing to produce any output. You have it below your `header()` stuff. It needs to go first.

See the first note here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 2):

If all domains are on same server, use these three lines everywhere before call to session_start

```
$session_name = session_name("somename");
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mysite.com');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'C:\tmp');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling the authenticate that runs the ajax request, to call auth.php and sets the session vars. you .load http://server.mysite.com/ajax/loader.php that calls session_start, but at no point do you call authenticate() so your session never gets filled.

Also, Access-Control-Allow-Origin isn't fully supported yet, so depending on the browser it may be blocking your cross-domain request.

Comment: I'm not seeing where this is cross-domain. Everything seems to be at mysite.com.

Comment: Cross-domain is also across subdomains this is calling the server subdomain from the main mysite.com domain, which would get blocked as cross-domain. Access-Control-Allow-Origin allows cross-domain but isn't fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have a login.html and there after the ajax execution, you have this main.php redirection page? Am I right? If this is the case, why won't you just simply redirect the user after form submission and let the server validates the authentication before it renders the page?

Now, if that is not the case, always be reminded that session data will not take effect when you set it by ajax and in your current page, you will call it. It definitely will not work.